# Fauxton behind Nginx is not fully working, what are the expected headers?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-headers, couchdb

Fauxton (CouchDB manager) behind Nginx is not fully working. Following Nginx block from [CouchDB Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy) is not working at all:

```
location /couchdb {
    rewrite /couchdb/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

When I change the `location /couchdb` part with `location ^~ /couchdb`, it starts working by displaying Fauxton at least.

Inspection (Chromium Inspector) shows the problem as the `/_session` url is requested from `https://example.com/_session` instead of  `https://example.com/couchdb/_session`, which means that Fauxton can not determine correctly that it is served within a subdirectory (adding a proxy block for `/_session` url solves the 404 issue) That's why I dumped the request on CouchDB host with `nc -l -p 5984` to see what the headers are set to:

```
GET /_utils/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Real-IP: 127.0.0.1
```

I'm not sure if `X-Forwarded-For` header is set correctly or not. What is the expected headers here? How can I determine if the problem is with my Nginx setup or there is another issue with - for example - my firewall (`iptables`) settings?

## Edit

Possible problem is with Fauxton, not with CouchDB: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues/944

Comment: Hmm, the `/_session` request does suggest something is using absolute urls, which obviously won't get proxied. The wiki does mention that Futon won't work (or at least didn't at the time) with links to a patch, nothing about Fauxton though. (I don't use CouchDB so have no real idea what any of this is...)  Ugly hack, but have you tried adding proxy blocks for any urls that you are seeing bad requests for, assuming that path isn't used on the main nginx server. (i.e. a proxy section to pass `/_session/(.*)` through to CouchDB?

Comment: Yes, I forget to mention that adding proxy blocks for `/_session`, `/_all_dbs`, etc solves those 404 issues, so we can be pretty sure that this hack will work if nothing would.

Comment: For the workaround: The mentioned workaround does not function flawlessly. Fauxton is fully and correctly rendered but when a new database is being created (for example, `foo`) the target url is calculated as `https://example.com/foo` instead of `https://example.com/couchdb/foo`, so no database can be created. Only workaround is creating an ssh tunnel for Fauxton at the moment.

Comment: I have it working with `proxy_buffering off;`

Comment: It looks like we have similar problems. See if this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/994736/how-to-host-couchdb-with-fauxton-at-a-non-root-location-using-nginx-as-reverse-p